# Eclipse decorates wrong Subversive URL

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I often notice Eclipse's SVN-Plugin `Subversive` decorates the wrong SVN-Repository.

[image]

Whereat the Project-Propertie's `Resource URL:` entry is correct!

[image]

How to Solve?

Comment: Update the plugin. If the problem still occurs, [report the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Subversive&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All).

Comment: Report the Bug to Eclipse? They will say: "Its a plugin!" :D

Comment: It is a plug-in which is actually within *incubation* (i.e., the Eclipse project manages it *officially*). Actually, if you go to the link I posted above, it automatically selects the *Subversive* component for the new issue in Bugzilla.